# Laravel Attach/Detach model from pivot depending on pivot extra field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a Many To Many relationship between Council and ManagementUnit. The associated entities change from year to year, so the pivot table is like this:

```
council_id
management_unit_id
year
```

My problem is that the same combined council_id + management_unit_id keys can appear several times, so I don't know how to attach() or detach() the models. For example, if I had this:

```
council_id | management_unit_id | year
1          | 1                  | 2010
1          | 1                  | 2011
1          | 1                  | 2012
```

how would I detach Council(1) from ManagementUnit(1) only for 2011?
or how would I attach a Council(1) to ManagementUnit(1) for 2013?

Working with Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure how your relations are set so you might have to adjust this a little. but give it a try:

```
$managementUnit = ManagementUnit::find(1);
$managementUnit->councils()->where('id', 1)->wherePivot('year', 2011)->detach(1);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!! I even had my relations like that :)

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 5.6 only worked with:

```
$managementUnit = ManagementUnit::find(1);
$managementUnit->councils()->where('conuncils.id', 1)->wherePivot('year', 2011)->detach();
```